# Angular 2 Material - Router animations broke sidenav content and scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, angular2-routing, angular-material2

I'm trying to add some router animations in my Angular 2 Material (angular/material2) application.
Without animations all works fine but when I add them to my components the content overflows the viewport and the scrolling behaviour does not work anymore.

To add animations I've defined a *ts* file *router.animations.ts*:

```
import { AnimationEntryMetadata, trigger, state, animate, style, transition } from "@angular/core";

export function slideToLeft(): AnimationEntryMetadata {
    "use strict";
    return trigger("slideToLeft", [
        state("void", style({ position: "fixed", width: "100%" })),
        state("*", style({ position: "fixed", width: "100%" })),
        transition(":enter", [
            style({ transform: "translateX(100%)" }),
            animate("0.5s ease-in-out", style({ transform: "translateX(0%)" }))
        ]),
        transition(":leave", [
            style({ transform: "translateX(0%)" }),
            animate("0.5s ease-in-out", style({ transform: "translateX(-100%)" }))
        ])
    ]);
}
```

Then inside my components:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { slideToLeft } from "./router.animations";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: "src/home.component.html",
    animations: [slideToLeft()],
    host: { "[@slideToLeft]": "" }
})
export class HomeComponent  {

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Here is a plunker which shows the issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Vz1iqSmcWwu3QG65Qxgw?p=preview

Ho can I solve this?

Comment: did you bit this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling is disabled because the component is set to "position: fixed" due to the animation. Changing the second state to "position: relative" and resetting the position in the leave transition will fix this:

```
export function slideToLeft(): AnimationEntryMetadata {
    "use strict";
    return trigger("slideToLeft", [
        state("void", style({ position: "fixed", width: "100%" })),
        state('*', style({position:'relative', width:'100%'}) ),
        transition(":enter", [
            style({ transform: "translateX(100%)" }),
            animate("0.5s ease-in-out", style({ transform: "translateX(0%)" }))
        ]),
        transition(":leave", [
            style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', position:'fixed', width:'100%'}),
            animate("0.5s ease-in-out", style({ transform: "translateX(-100%)" }))
        ])
    ]);
}
```